# Try to not repeat function in Lua

Tags: lua

There is a way to not rewrite the same part (the cycle `for i = 1...end`) twice?

```
local function myfunc(frame,method)
    if frame:IsShown() then
        for i = 1, #frame.buttons do
            frame.buttons[i]:HookScript("OnMouseDown", method)
        end
    else
        self:SetScript(
            "OnShow",
            function(frame)
                for i = 1, #frame.buttons do
                    frame.buttons[i]:HookScript("OnMouseDown", method)
                end
            end
        )
    end
end
```

Where

- `IsShown()`, `HookScript()` and `SetScript()` are all in-game API

Answer (score 1):

**Not** a completely review, but this should work as intended:

```lua
local function myfunc(frame)
    function hookFunc(frame)
        for i = 1, #frame.buttons do
            frame.buttons[i]:HookScript("OnMouseDown", method)
        end
    end
    if frame:IsShown() then
        hookFunc(frame)
    else
        self:SetScript(
            "OnShow",
            hookFunc(frame)
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: I forgot the `method` argument in my original code.

Comment: My code should be adaptable accordingly.

Comment: For more explanation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665384/lua-how-to-properly-construct-nested-functions).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a recursive function? It seems to work:

```
local function myfunc(frame,method)
    if frame:IsShown() then
        for i = 1, #frame.buttons do
            frame.buttons[i]:HookScript("OnMouseDown", method)
        end
    else
        frame:SetScript(
            "OnShow", --when "OnShow" is fired, IsShown() become true
            function()
                myfunc(frame,method)
            end
        )
    end
end
```